# getText method is not getting ellipsis in text ? How to get text that contains ellipsis?

Tags: ios, appium

In my iOS app, one button element contains text "abc...me".[image]

But when I use `getText()` method to get text of this element, it is returning me full text `abchsshshme`. But I am expecting the shortened "abc...me".

In xml it is showing full name abchsshshme but in UI it is showing abc...me.

Can I do this in appium?

Comment: Can you please attach the screen shot of the screen from Appium Inspector?

Comment: Hi added picture in xml it is showing full text instead of ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?,

```
WebElement uiElement1 = driver.findElementById("ElementId of abc...me Button");
String text = uiElement1.getText().replace("abchsshshme", "abc...me");
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Hi Raman   what is the benefit of doing this? We are manually changing the text but what i want is appium automatically get text as abc...me without replace method

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of that Button contained activity.

Comment: Hi added picture, in xml it is showing full text instead of ellipsis

Comment: @DevduttaGoyal did you find a way to fix this issue? I am stuck with same issue, please let me know if you have found any solution.